# CakePHP - How to check in beforeSave if it's an INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my model's `beforeSave` method, how can I check if the save operation is going to be an INSERT or an UPDATE?

I want to add to the model data, but only if it's inserting a new row.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just check in the data if the `id` exists:

```
function beforeSave($options = array())
{
  if(empty($this->data[$this->alias]['id']))
  {
    //INSERT
  }
  else
  {
    //UPDATE
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty simple, I don't know why I didn't think of this... :/

Thanks!

Comment: Update: in Cake 2.3 you should check if $this->id is empty.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would do in Cakephp 4 (in case someone is looking for it)

**EDIT** it also applies to Cakephp 3 as BadHorsie stated

```
public function beforeSave(EventInterface $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
       //INSERT
    }else{
       //UPDATE
    }
}
```

Comment: [It applies to CakePHP 3 as well](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-was-persisted)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    if($this->id) {
        // Update
    } else {
        // Add
    }
}
```